# Formal proof for conjuction elimination (simplification rule) in natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Were working with the natural deduction system:

- $(A0): \Gamma \vdash B \text{ whenever }B \in \Gamma$
- $(A1): \Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$
- $(A2): \Gamma \vdash (A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$
- $(A2): \Gamma \vdash (\neg B \rightarrow \neg A) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$
- $$(MP): \frac{\Gamma \vdash A;\;\;\Gamma\vdash A \rightarrow B}{\Gamma \vdash B}$$

As an exercise, we are to show that $$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A \land B}{\Gamma \vdash A}$$ is admissible, while we defined $A \land B =^{def} \neg (A \rightarrow \neg B)$.

As intuitive as it seems, I have already tried for some hours to show that the conjunction elimination is provable, but failed and I think it might not even be possible without additional rules or axioms, as I have come mostly across systems that have the rule built in.

Is this rule really derivable or am I missing an important point?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Deduction Theorem?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: Are there some other results that you can use that have already been proven? E.g. $A\to (\neg A \to B)$, or $(\neg A \to A) \to A$, or $\neg \neg A \to A$?

Comment: There are some rules (like the third one you mentioned) that we have proven already, but nothing seemed particularly helpful to me.

Comment: Is there a source where this system is called "natural deduction"? It looks to  me like a typical Hilbert-style system.

Comment: We called it the $\vdash_{\mathcal{N}}$ system "as it corresponds closely with natural deduction as it satisfies the deduction theorem". From the lack of a proper name I just called the system "Natural deduction". We also showed its equivalence to the Hilbert-system, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's useful to break down the proof into pieces. I call $(A3)$ your fourth axiom (you have named both the third and the fourth $(A2)$).

First you want to prove

$(A4): A\rightarrow \lnot\lnot A$.

You mention that you have already proved the converse $\lnot\lnot A\rightarrow A$. Substituting $\lnot A$ for $A$, you obtain $\lnot\lnot\lnot A\rightarrow \lnot A$. Now use $(A3)$ to get $(A4)$.

Next we will prove

$(A5): \lnot A\rightarrow( A\rightarrow \lnot B)$.

This follows from $(A1):\lnot A\rightarrow(\lnot\lnot B\rightarrow \lnot A)$ and $(A3):(\lnot\lnot B\rightarrow\lnot A)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow\lnot B)$

[**update, some more detail for this step:** From $(\lnot\lnot B\rightarrow\lnot A)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow\lnot B)$ infer $\lnot A\rightarrow((\lnot\lnot B\rightarrow\lnot A)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow\lnot B))$ using $(A1)$, and then $(A2)$ gives $(\lnot A\rightarrow (\lnot\lnot B\rightarrow\lnot A))\rightarrow (\lnot A\rightarrow (A\rightarrow\lnot B))$. Now use $\lnot A\rightarrow (\lnot\lnot B\rightarrow\lnot A)$ to get the desired $\lnot A\rightarrow( A\rightarrow \lnot B)$.]

Now the rest of the proof goes as follows: From $(A5)$ and $(A4):(A\rightarrow \lnot B)\rightarrow\lnot\lnot(A\rightarrow\lnot B)$ you get $\lnot A\rightarrow \lnot\lnot(A\rightarrow\lnot B)$. Then from $(A3)$ you get $\lnot(A\rightarrow\lnot B)\rightarrow A$.

Finally, by assumption of your exercise you have a proof of $A\land B:=\lnot(A\rightarrow\lnot B)$, and so you get $A$ using $(MP)$.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! When I tried, I got stuck at trying to prove $\Gamma \vdash \neg A \rightarrow \neg\neg(A \rightarrow \neg B)$. Any insight on how you found that proof or was it just intuition?

Comment: "This follows from (A1) ... and (A3)" - I think you are using deduction theorem at that point

Comment: I don't think he is, as $$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B \; ; \; \Gamma \vdash B \rightarrow C}{\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow C}$$ should be provable without deduction theorem

Comment: Yes sorry, I was a bit sloppy there - you need to use the transitivity rule that @AnonymousUser mentions, which is essentially axiom $(A2)$. I'll update the answer.